# QField project accidently overwritten by importing new project

Tags: qgis, qfield, qgs

In QField on Android, I imported an (old) version of my project and overwrote by mistake the current project and all data is not there anymore. I was  mainly  working in shapes of a geopackage and I was creating and editing new points...
Is there a possibility  to restore the data of the overwritten project?

Comment: The only chance would be to try some undelete software on your phone.

Comment: @user207763 Were you working on local data or using QFieldCloud?